# How do I set an integer to null in f#?

Tags: c#, .net, f#

In C#, I can declare a nullable type like so:

```
int? myNullableInt;
```

I'm trying to do some interop and need to declare and set a nullable type in F#, so I've declared a class like this:

```
type TestEntity() =
    member val OptionalValue = Nullable(1) with get, set
```

Later I'm trying to assign it like so:

```
let testEnt = TestEntity()
testEnt.Optional <- null
```

But it doesn't work.

What's the correct way to do this in F#? Also, at the interop layer, will this behave the same as `int?` does in C#?

Comment: [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/symbol-and-operator-reference/nullable-operators)?

Comment: Might want to read the compiler error: `The type 'Nullable<int>' does not have 'null' as a proper value. To create a null value for a Nullable type use 'System.Nullable()'.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
testEnt.OptionalValue <- Nullable()
```

1. You needed to use the same name as the optional property you declared.
2. `null` isn't really a valid value for Value Types to have. Even though C# does some magic and syntax sugar to treat `null` as if it were compatible with `Nullable<T>` types, what you really end up with when you assign `null` to an `int?` in C# is a `default(Nullable<int>)` (aka `new Nullable<int>()`). F# doesn't add this syntax sugar, so you have to be more explicit about it. But outside of language-specific changes, the CLR will treat it the same way it would treat a `Nullable<int>` from C#.

Comment: Ok, so F# Nullable<int> is compatible with the C# `int?` then (just to be 100% clear haha)?

Comment: [`System.Nullable(T)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) is defined in mscorelib and used by both C# and F#.

Comment: @RodYan C# `int?` is a synonym for `System.Nullable<int>`. They're the same thing.

Comment: Yeah, I added some content to clarify. `int?` == `System.Nullalbe<int>`. You don't get all the same syntax sugar in F#, but the behavior is the same.

Comment: PS--TheInnerLight makes a good point that `null` and `Nullable<>` kind of clash with the whole functional paradigm of F#, and you should use `Option<>` where possible.

Comment: Thanks! I'm testing some interop things with the AzureStorage APIs and playing around with nullable. I do prefer to avoid null.

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend avoiding values that might be `null` like the plague in F#, you should work with `Option<'T>` and convert to `Nullable<'T>` at the C# boundary.

You can convert from `Option<'T>` to `Nullable<'T>` using `Option.toNullable`.

You can convert from `Nullable<'T>` to `Option<'T>` using `Option.ofNullable`.

```
testEnt.Optional <- Option.toNullable None

testEnt.Optional <- Option.toNullable (Some 5)
```